# Как в файле логов найти последнюю информацию по IP

Tags: php

Есть файл test.log:

```
2015-08-17 15:37:22;server;FAIL;100.100.100.101 
2015-08-17 15:37:32;server;FAIL;100.100.100.102
2015-08-17 15:47:58;client;ACTIVATE;100.100.100.103
2015-08-17 15:48:13;server;ACTIVATE;100.100.100.102
2015-08-17 15:48:13;server;ACTIVATE;100.100.100.101
2015-08-17 15:51:02;client;ACTIVATE;100.100.100.103;
```

При подсчете количества строк в файле через php методом `count();` получаю результат `1`. т.е одна длинная строка.
Как мне получить снизу вверх последнюю дату от ip `100.100.100.102`, в этом примере хочу получить `2015-08-17 15:48:13` т.е снизу вверх последняя значение от `100.100.100.102`.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста ваш код. Пока что вопрос звучит "напишите за меня"

Comment: От чего вы берете count() и какое он отношение имеет к поиску строк ?

Comment: "Как определить последние строка" - выучите русский язык для начала

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `count` никак не решит вашу задачу.

Ознакомьтесь с методом в документации http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php

**UPDATED**

## Вариант перебора №1

```
$search_ip = '100.100.100.102';
$log_path = 'test.log';
$log_data = explode("\n", file_get_contents($log_path));

$result = NULL;
foreach (array_reverse($log_data) as $str) {
    $data = explode(';', $str);
    if ($data[3] == $search_ip) {
        $result = $data;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

## Вариант перебора №2

```
$search_ip = '100.100.100.102';
$log_path = 'test.log';
$log_data = explode("\n", file_get_contents($log_path));
$found = array_filter($log_data, function($val) use ($search_ip) {
    return strpos($val, $search_ip) > 0;
});

$result = explode(';', end($found));
```

---

## Вариант №3 через `grep` (для unix)

```
$search_ip = '100.100.100.102';
$log_path = 'test.log';

$result = NULL;
if ($output = shell_exec("grep $search_ip $log_path")) {
    $result = explode(';', end(array_filter(explode("\n", $output))));
}
```

---

#### В переменной `$result` получаем

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-08-17 15:48:13
    [1] => server
    [2] => ACTIVATE
    [3] => 100.100.100.102
)
```

Comment: А чем `file_get_contents` лучше на больших объемах? ... вместо `$log_data = explode("\n", file_get_contents($log_path));`  можно `$log_data = file($log_path);`  и вместо того чтобы в цикле постоянно вызывать `array_reverse` лучше отдельно операцию до цикла сделать

Comment: Где это в цикле вызывается array_reverse? Вы заблуждаетесь.

Comment: Разве `array_reverse($log_data)` не каждый раз вызывается в итерации?

Comment: Нет, только один раз

Comment: А что на счет объема? Почему это лучше чтения перебором?

Comment: Так в конечном итоге ты перебором весь логфайл и пройдешь, за ранее не известно на каком индексе будет нужное значение. Есть еще один хардкорный вариант через `grep` информацию выудить из файла. Тут нужно `benchmark` запускать и смотреть какой самый оптимальный вариант. Мне не известно какой объем данных автор собирается парсить. Если большой, то пусть хранит логи в NoSQL и оттуда выдергивает.

Comment: Добавил реализацию с `grep`

Answer (score -2):

Используйте fopen и fgets:

```
$handle = @fopen("/test.log", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) { // 4096 - максимальная длина строки
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Во-первых надо файл взять и строки потом смотреть с конца.... во-вторых - еще парсинг, чтоб вынуть нужные данные. а  у вас что?